# Sublime SFTP tunneling

Tags: ssh, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sftp, tunnel

To connect to my_computer from my_laptop at work I do the next thing:

1. `ssh -XY <login>@<commonserver>`
2. `ssh <my_computer>`
3. enter the password

Now, I want to edit some files on my_computer from my_laptop via sublime 2 and SFTP plugin.

Unfortunately the next configuration doesn't work:

```
"host": "my_computer.commonserver"
```

How can I do it? 
How should I set-up the sftp-server file?

Additional question:
Is there a way to set-up the sftp-server file in the way it will ignore welcoming message when I log-in via ssh?